# background:url("javascript:...") doesn't work anymore?

Tags: css, security, xss

I'm studying about XSS prevention as a front-end engineer.

According to [OWASP document](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#STYLE_tag_using_background), following code should be filtered from user input. But when I tested it in my chrome and safari browsers, it seems doesn't work.

```
<STYLE type="text/css">BODY{background:url("javascript:alert('XSS')")}</STYLE>
```

Is this forbidden by nowadays browsers?

Comment: So no problem - it looks like the browser vendors have closed the hole. You could try it out on older browsers to see which are vulnerable. See here: http://www.oldapps.com/category/browsers

Comment: Don't rely on it, though.

Comment: The phrasing "following code should be prevented. But this doesn't work" is extremely confusing. So is this code alerting XSS for you or not?

Comment: @BoltClock, sorry for confusing. I meant that the code must be filtered from user input. It is valid code and no problem if it is used by web engineer intentionally. But it would be harmful when a web service let a user input a code like that because a user could insert a harmful javascript code to webpage(XSS code injection).

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff, this code would be valid and not a browser hole. So I just want to check this is really forbidden by browsers and if so, since when it is..

Comment: hi joybro , I think you need to state a minimum browser requirement - so that browsers older than a certain time/version are not used - because your example is not forbidden in those older browsers - they remain unpatched and vulnerbable.

Comment: It looks like browsers patched those scripts in style url. Refer to following;

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=377092

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1018583

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff Thank you for answer. It turned out that the code worked in old browsers but not anymore. But I will filter them because many people  still uses old browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this was an attack vector in old versions of Internet Explorer (version 6 IIRC).

It would still be good practice to disallow this in case any of your users are still using an old browser, or in the case that a browser vendor reintroduces this functionality for any reason.

I've [found a reference for this here](http://blog.innerht.ml/cascading-style-scripting/):

> In IE 6, javascript pseudo scheme executes in any URI.
>
> `<input style="background: url(javascript:alert(1))">`

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer and reference!